# How to store the numbers obtained from the rand() function in the for loop?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

Please tell me how I can store the numbers obtained from `g` and the print them:
Example: `2,2,6`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int nrzaruri;
    int g;
    int valori;
    int array[g];
    printf("cate zaruri arunci?\n");
    scanf("%d", &nrzaruri);
    for (int i = 1; i <= nrzaruri; i++) {
        g = (rand() % 6) + 1;
        printf("zarul %d\n are valoarea %d\n", i, g);
    }
}
```

Comment: there are some variable which i don't used,skip them

Comment: But perhaps you should *not* skip them! The array named `array`, for example, could be put to good use (if only you'd initialize it properly).

Comment: `int array[6]={0};` .. `array[g-1]++;` or `int stock[nrzaruri]` .. `stock[i-1] = g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly what you need is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{    
    int nrzaruri;

    printf( "cate zaruri arunci?\n" );
    scanf( "%d", &nrzaruri );

    int array[nrzaruri];

    for ( int i = 0; i < nrzaruri; i++ ) 
    {
        int g = ( rand() % 6 ) + 1;
        array[i] = g;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < nrzaruri; i++ ) 
    {    
        printf( "zarul %d\n are valoarea %d\n", i + 1, array[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can substitute these two statements

```
        int g = ( rand() % 6 ) + 1;
        array[i] = g;
```

for this one

```
        array[i] = ( rand() % 6 ) + 1;
```

I simply used your variables.

Or if you need to output the elements of the array in one line then you can use the following loop

```
int i = 0;
do
{    
    printf( "%d", array[i] );
} while (  ++i < nrzaruri &&  printf( ", " ) > 0 );
```

The output will look like

```
2, 5, 4, 2, 6, 2, 5, 1, 4, 2
```

Comment: Thank you for writing that; I was debating whether to write more or less the code you did too.

Comment: thank you for your answer,can you tell me one more thing?in printf("%d",%x),what %x means?

Comment: @Alex Sturza it means to outpit integral values in the hexadecimal notation.